# 403 OPTIONS Cors error in AWS, preflight requests

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed React JS + Spring boot app to AWS Cloud. My React JS project is stored in S3 bucket which reference is used in CloudFront. Spring boot app is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk Service.

When I try make any request to backend from CloudFront distribution I get 403 error OPTIONS Cors which is following:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.divelog.eu/getuserdata/eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRB' from origin 'https://divelog.eu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have enabled CORS at the server side in Spring Boot:

```
@Component
public class CustomCorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Allow, authorization, content-type, xsrf-token");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
    if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
}

also 

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SocialConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**",
                    "/signin", "/getuserdata/**", "/add/marker/**", "/get/markers/**", "/delete/marker/**/**",
                    "/logout/**", "/add/logbook/**/**", "/get/logbook/**", "/logbook/**/**", "/**/**", "/edit/logbook/**/**",
                    "/pdf/logbook/**/**", "/add/topic", "/get/topic/posts/**", "/add/post", "/delete/post/**/**", "/post/**/**",
                    "/delete/post/file/**/**", "/get/topic/number/comments/**/**", "/update/topic/number/displays/**",
                    "/topic/likes/vote/**/**", "/update/topic/**", "/callback", "/signin", "/oauth/request_token")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()

            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
}
}
```

In React JS project I pass to fetch and axios those headers: Accept, Content-Type.

My CORS in AWS S3 buckets for Spring boot and React JS are set to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Spring boot app hich is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk works fine when I try get access to endpoints via Postman, only if I try make request from S3 bucket instance to backend API I get cors error.

I have added listeners for 443 and 80 HTTP HTTPS port in load balancer of elastic beanstalk instance.

Have you got any idea why I still get this error ?

[image: I upload picture to request info]

2. CloudFront Behaviors

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this JSON configuration to S3 bucket's permissions.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Range",
            "Accept",
            "Content-Type",
            "Origin",
            "Range"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Content-Range",
            "Content-Length",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your backend api.divelog.eu still haven't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you can see in the response with status code 403 there still no`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header.

This header must be sent from the backend into the client browser to prevent cors.

Reference: 
https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

Comment: Where should I set this cors ? I have enabled cors at server side. So, my configuration in Spring boot propably does not work ?

Comment: When I change in React JS fetch request to mode: 'no-cors' -> all the requested headers are in the response headers. It looks like a bug. I think that should be when I make request, but I don't want with mode: 'no-cors'. When I try request withoud cors I get net::ERR_ABORTED.

Comment: When you changed the client request header `Sec-Fetch-Mode` into `no-cors` you got  a response from your back-end?

Comment: I found error. I commented out this line .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class); in configure method and everything works fine. Thanks for reply !